# python msrestazure package throws Tunnel connection failed error

Tags: python, azure

Python msrestazure(0.4.20V) is throwing below error:

```
    credentials = UserPassCredentials(userid, password)
    File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 367, in __init__
    self.set_token()
    File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 404, in set_token
    raise_with_traceback(AuthenticationError, "", err)
    File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py", line 45, in raise_with_traceback
    raise error.with_traceback(exc_traceback)
   File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py", line 402, in set_token
**optional)
   File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 221, in fetch_token
verify=verify, proxies=proxies)
   File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in post
  return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 360, in request
headers=headers, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/data/tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
msrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/oauth2/token (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
```

We used correct azure credentials, Any idea?

Edit:

This issue is coming up again, this time from different exception `requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/UserRealm/username%40<dns>.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.0 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))`

Comment: Could you update to at least 0.5.0 and try again? UserPassCredentials has been re-implemented.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel- Tried by upgrading msrestazure to 0.5.0, but getting same error.

Comment: I was using from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials. Changed this to from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import UserPassCredentials. And now its working

Comment: @LaurentMazuel - This issue is coming up again, this time from different exception
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/UserRealm/username%40<dns>.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.0 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))

Comment: Can you open an issue on msrestazure on Github, so I can tag the authentication expert. Thanks!